# Sometimes the resulting PDF doesn't allow copy image

Tags: graphics, pdftex, acrobat

In case it matters I am using TeXnicCenter with miktex, LaTeX => PDF configuration.

If I do the following:

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.08]{figure.png}
```

I get a PDF which looks fine in Adobe Reader.  And when the cursor is over the image, it becomes a cross.  Selecting it the image is highlighted and I can copy image to the clipboard with a right click.  This is quite handy.

Now if I use

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.07]{figure.png}
```

or any smaller scaling, the pdf looks fine, but the copy image just results in a large black square in the clipboard (still of the correct size though).

Searching around, all I've found a [thread on LinuxQuestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/why-doesnt-copy-image-work-in-adobe-acrobat-reader-762271/)
which reports a similar problem (not related to the scaling). Which notes that this is due to a single image sometimes getting stored as multiple overlays in the pdf.  They give an alternative way to copy the images (which is inconvenient for non-linux users), but don't give information for how to write the latex to avoid this in the first place.

Is there someway to fix this?

Comment: This is nothing to do with TeX - the image will be included in the same way in both cases. It's down to Reader.

Comment: Did you tried to to zoom in and try it again.

Comment: I'd day also assume a Reader problem. You use Adobe Reader X, I presume? Ever since I use X instead of 9, it also commonly fails at copying code from PDF (e.g. pgfmanual.pdf) which never happened before.

Answer (score 3):

(Originaly posted as comments by Joseph Wright and Tom Bombadil)

This has nothing to do with TeX -- the image will be included in the same way in both cases. It's a Reader problem. Note that Adobe Reader X -- unlike version 9 -- also commonly fails at copying code from PDF (e.g. pgfmanual.pdf).